# Computing the average of non-negative numbers from a text file

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement, for-loop, accumulator

I am trying to read in a text file of integers, make it a list, compute the average of all integers, compute the average of all non-negative integers, print max and min. I was able to compute the average of all integers but am having difficulty getting the average of all non-negative integers and the max and min.

Here is what I have so far:

```
file = open("numberlist.txt", "r")

sum = 0

list = []
for num in file:
    list.append(num)

poslist = []
for number in file:
    x = int(number)
    if x > 0:
        poslist.append(x)
        sum += number
posavg = sum / len(poslist)
print("The number of non-negative integers is ", len(poslist))
print("The average of the non-negtive integers is ", posavg)
```

Answer (score 0):

If the numbers are separated by spaces
(or, as I understand from your code, by new lines)
this is a very short and *"Pythonic"* task!

First, let's read the entire file into numbers
and also have the file close automatically:

```
with open('numberlist.txt') as f:
    nums = [int(x) for x in f.read().split() if int(x) >= 0]
```

After the previous 2 line you have all the non-negative
numbers in a list called `nums`!

Now, the average would be:

```
avg = sum(nums) / len(nums)
```

And the min/max would be:

```
minNum, maxNum = min(nums), max(nums)
```

And that's all!

Now, I pushed as much Python as I think is possible
into this task, so by understanding this code you make 
a leap in Python!

Answer (score 0):

This keeps most of your code and adds the non-negative part to it (perhaps should be called positive instead? :)

```
file = open("numberlist.txt", "r")

sum = 0
nonNegativeTotal = 0
nonNegativeCount = 0

list = []
for num in file:
    list.append(num)

for number in list:
    x = int(number)
    if x >= 0:
        nonNegativeCount += 1
        nonNegativeTotal += x
    sum += x
avg = sum/len(list)
avgNonNegative = nonNegativeTotal/nonNegativeCount
print("The number of integers is ", len(list))
print("The overall average is ", avg)
print("The number of non-negative numbers is ", nonNegativeCount)
print("The non-negative average is ", avgNonNegative)

list.sort()
print("The minimum number is ", list[0])
print("The maximum number is ", list[-1])
```

For the min and max you could do:

```
minNum, maxNum = min(list), max(list)
```